# Top Left Coordinates of ImageView in Android displaying incorrectly

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I have an ImageView in an activity, whose top left coordinates I must retrieve so I can divide the the imageview into 5 touch zones. I use getLocationOnScreen to get these coordinates.

The X coordinate is fine however the Y coordinate seems faulty for some reason, there is always an offset and it seems to point to the top of the window( Verified this by enabling pointer touches in dev tools).

Here is the activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    amslerView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.amsler_grid);

    locText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationLabel);

    amslerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    startX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    startY = (int) event.getRawY();

                    int[] loc = new int[2];
                    amslerView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
                    Log.i("Screen Location of View", "X:" + loc[0] + "\t Y:" + loc[1]);

                    locText.setText("Location " + startX + " " + startY + "Screen View Location is " + "X:" + loc[0] + "\t Y:" + loc[1]);

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                    endX = (int) event.getX();
                    endY = (int) event.getY();

                    // locText.setText("End Location " + endX + "\t" +
                    // endY);
                    break;

            }

            return true;

        }
    });

}
```

Here is the XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/amsler_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="Amsler Grid"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/amsler_boundary" />
```

And this is a screenshot of the problem I'm facing: http://puu.sh/4d1LJ.jpg

As you can see, the X coordinate is fine, but the Y coordinate shows the location http://puu.sh/4d1OJ.jpg

Any help is appreciated, I'm frankly at a loss why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what was wrong, the Y offset is due to the fact that the height of both status bar and ActionBar are taken into account. So in my case the offset was 108( 75 for the ActionBar and 33 for the Status Bar). Writing two functions to calculate these heights and subtracting them from the value returned by getRawY() solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                startX = (int) event.getRawX();
                startY = (int) event.getRawY();
```

Try this

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Get X, Y coordinates from the ImageView
                X = (int) event.getX();
                Y = (int) event.getY();
```

Comment: This is what I get when using getX() <http://puu.sh/4d4b7.jpg>. I've tried almost every combination of code to try and get the coordinates but so far there's always the offset in Y.